# AVL binary search tree implementation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Is there any text-book implementation of self-balancing binary search trees such as AVL or red-black in *Mathematica*?

Comment: *The Mathematica Coobook* has an implementation of a red-black tree, take a look [here](https://books.google.se/books?id=BkDxC_O1WisC&lpg=PA125&ots=hkhVLhIEG_&dq=mathematica%20cookbook%20tree&pg=PA125#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: The Mathematica Cookbook's description of deletion from red-black trees is completely wrong.